# Magento 2 - products GET with "searchCriteria" always returns "401 unauthorized" in nodejs OAuth

Tags: node.js, axios, oauth-2.0, magento2

I'm in a pickle here. I am developing an application on magento 2 using nodejs. This is how I'm authenticating with the api with a JS class:

```
class MagentoClient {
  private oauth: OAuth;
  private token: OAuth.Token;
  private baseUrl: string;

  constructor({
    consumerKey,
    consumerSecret,
    accessToken,
    accessTokenSecret,
    baseUrl,
  }: MagentoApiOptions) {
    this.oauth = new OAuth({
      consumer: {
        key: consumerKey,
        secret: consumerSecret,
      },
      signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA256',
      hash_function: (base_string, key) => {
        return crypto
          .createHmac('sha256', key)
          .update(base_string)
          .digest('base64');
      },
    });

    this.token = {
      key: accessToken,
      secret: accessTokenSecret,
    };

    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  }


  // THIS FUNCTION DOES WORK
    async getProducts<T>(): Promise<any> {
    console.log(`https://${this.baseUrl}/rest/V1/products`)
    const storeConfigs = await this.getStoreConfigs();
    if (!storeConfigs) {
      logger.error('Store configs not found');
      return;
    };
    const mediaUrl = storeConfigs[0].baseMediaUrl;
    const request: OAuth.RequestOptions = {
      url: `https://${this.baseUrl}/rest/default/V1/products`,
      method: 'GET',
    };
    // SEARCH CRITERIA WORKS
    const additionalParams = '?searchCriteria';
    const authorization = this.oauth.toHeader(this.oauth.authorize(request, this.token));
    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      method: request.method,
      url: `${request.url}${additionalParams}`,
      headers: {
        ...authorization,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    try {
      const response: any = await axios(config);
      return response.data.items.map((product: any) => ({
        ...product,
        media_gallery_entries: product.media_gallery_entries.map((mediaGalleryEntry: any) => ({
          ...mediaGalleryEntry,
          file: `${mediaUrl}catalog/product${mediaGalleryEntry.file}`
        }))
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      logger.error(error.response.data.message);
    }
  };


  
  // THIS FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK
  async getProducts<T>(): Promise<any> {
    console.log(`https://${this.baseUrl}/rest/V1/products`)
    const storeConfigs = await this.getStoreConfigs();
    if (!storeConfigs) {
      logger.error('Store configs not found');
      return;
    };
    const mediaUrl = storeConfigs[0].baseMediaUrl;
    const request: OAuth.RequestOptions = {
      url: `https://${this.baseUrl}/rest/default/V1/products`,
      method: 'GET',
    };
    // SEARCH CRITERIA DOESN'T WORK
    const additionalParams = '?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1';
    const authorization = this.oauth.toHeader(this.oauth.authorize(request, this.token));
    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      method: request.method,
      url: `${request.url}${additionalParams}`,
      headers: {
        ...authorization,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    try {
      const response: any = await axios(config);
      return response.data.items.map((product: any) => ({
        ...product,
        media_gallery_entries: product.media_gallery_entries.map((mediaGalleryEntry: any) => ({
          ...mediaGalleryEntry,
          file: `${mediaUrl}catalog/product${mediaGalleryEntry.file}`
        }))
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      logger.error(error.response.data.message);
    }
  };

  
  
}
```

I have included two versions of the same function to make it easy to read. As you can see, when i append just "?searchCriteria" onto the end of the products url, it returns all the products, however when i try to add params, e.g. "?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1", it always returns this message `data: { message: 'The signature is invalid. Verify and try again.' }` - `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401`

I am following the documentation exactly, as referenced [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html). I've tried many different combinations of the `searchCriteria` and still nothing works.

Very confused by this error. I have opened the scope of the credentials to allow everything, so the integration definitely has the permissions. I have also carbon copied the syntax from the official magento documentation, so I've also ruled that out.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Been stuck on this for a couple of days!

Cheers